# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'natsu' django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, valueerror

I want to create a user_posts view that has all the posts related to a particular user let's say there is/are blog posts written by a user 'Natsu' then a logged-in user let's say 'Testuser' will be able to see all posts by that user i.e. all posts of user 'Natsu'.

`blog models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
  body = models.TextField()
```

`user models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic', default='default.jpg')

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{ self.user.username } Profile'
```

`views.py`

```
def user_posts(request, username):
  posts = Post.objects.filter(author=username)
  return render(request, 'blog/user_posts.html', {'posts':posts})
```

`user_posts.html`

```
{% for post in posts %}
      <a href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}" class="mr-2">{{ post.author }}</a>
      <h2><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      {{ post.body|truncatewords:30 }} 
{% endfor %}
```

`urls.py`

```
  path('user/<str:username>/', views.user_posts, name='user-posts'),
```

but when I go to that url it shows me error `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'.`

full traceback is here:

```
Internal Server Error: /user/natsu/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'natsu'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner     
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response 
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response 
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\OneDrive\Desktop\Virtual Environment\mysite\blog\views.py", line 78, in user_posts
    posts = Post.published.filter(author=username)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method  
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q       
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q      
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__        
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in 
get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Sheraram Prajapat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'natsu'.
[29/Jun/2020 17:47:37] "GET /user/natsu/ HTTP/1.1" 500 127097
```

where am I doing wrong? Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`author` on `Post` would be the primary key of the `User` table which is an integer (unless modified from the default) and not the `username`.  You either need to look up the `username` first is `User` or use some other Django 'magic'.  Maybe try one of these (I think they both do the same thing in the backend):

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(author=User.object.filter(username=username)[:1])
```

or

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)
```

(I didn't test either... so please free to edit this answer or comment if either don't work)

Comment: Note that the first option requires double queries.

Comment: @Tim Tisdall, posts = Post.objects.filter(author=User.object.filter(username=username))
 this gives error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Comment: I think the first could be `Post.objects.filter(author=User.object.filter(username=username)[:1])`, but the second is far more readable.

Comment: @mattarello - The first one is a single query due to lazy loading. Django recognizes it can handle that with a subquery and it does a single query with a subquery. (I didn't specifically check, but I'm pretty sure that's how it works in both versions; with a subquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
```

As you used a foreignkey for the auhor field I think you can't filter it by  `posts = Post.objects.filter(author=username)`. Can you try `filter(author=user.id)`?

Comment: You may be able to do something like `Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)`

Comment: @ Tim Tisdall ,thank you. Post.objects.filter(author__username=username) worked as expected. @mattarello please can you explain how would I pass user id of that person who has written blog?

Comment: for that you have to change you path to path ('user/<str:username>/<int:id>', views.user_posts, name='user-posts'). make the same adaptation in your view as:(request,username,id):. @TimTisdall's solution is far better, I'd stick with it.

Comment: The only problem is often `username` is used for logins and you'd be exposing that via a URL.  Also, you may want to test what happens if a username contains a '/'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  posts = Post.objects.filter(author=User.object.get(username=username))
```

or

```
  posts = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)
```

Comment: ... you just duplicated my answer (with the error I've since corrected)