# Django view order history

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a function where admin can click on the username of a customer and view the customer's order history. So far I'm only able to view all orders of a user that is logged in. If I'm logged in as admin, my template displays all the orders created by different customers. And If I'm logged in as a customer I can only view my own orders. I want to add an additional function, where if I'm logged in as admin I want to be able to click on the username of any customer and view his/her order history.The problem I'm facing is I can only view the order history of a logged in user , but not of the user I have clicked on.

```
views.py
def order_history(request, user):
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=user)

    context = {
        'order_qs': order_qs,
    }
    return render(request, "order_history.html", context)
```

```
order_history.html

{%  for order in order_qs  %}
  {{ order.user }}
    {{ order.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: plz add models.py file

Comment: @Sheraram_Prajapat Already!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC I have clarified now

Comment: @dummy You added some more detail on what you want, but what is the actual issue?

Comment: @AMC The problem I'm facing is I can only view the order history of a logged in user , but not of the user I have clicked on.

Comment: @AMC he want to sort out blog post related to a perticular user if u relate to blog project and that way he want all orders made by a perticular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` on Post would be the primary key of the User table which is an integer (unless modified from the default) and not the `username`. You either need to look up the username first is User or use some other Django 'magic'. Maybe try one of these (I think they both do the same thing in the backend):

```
def order_history(request, username):
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user__username=username)

    context = {
        'order_qs': order_qs,
    }
    return render(request, "order_history.html", context)
```

It should work.
For more information, take a look at answers of question [Field 'id' expected a number but got 'natsu' django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638087/field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-natsu-django/62638449#62638449)

Comment: It displays nothing on the order_history.html template. Could it be I'm passing username in the URL as a primarykey ?path('orderhistory/<str:username>/',order_history, name='order-history'),

Comment: Yes, since your view is taking ``` username``` as a parameter. Also to link order_histery.html use <a href='{% url 'order-history' order.user.username %}' > {{ order.user }} </a>